# Can we have accent in tags here?

Tags: feature-request, tags

We have tags with special characters on Stack Overflow em Português. Can we have the same feature implemented here?

Comment: Related on Meta.StackExchange: [Add non-Latin character set support for tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags) (status-completed)